# SharePoint 2010: Using values specified through a modal dialog in web part code behind

Tags: dialog-framework, web-part

In my custom SharePoint 2010 web part, I am allowing the user to specify his information in a model dialog window. I then need to use this information in my web part code behind for further processing.

But I am not pretty sure as how to read this information back in my managed code.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If your modal dialog was actually just a seperate

```
<div>
```

tag in your web part which was shown/hidden by the SharePoint dialog framework then you can just treat the controls in the dialog as you would any other control.

There is further info on rendering a div as a dialog here:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/05/27/client-side-ajax-applications-in-sharepoint-2010-%E2%80%93-part-5-modal-dialogs/

Comment: Thanks Charls for pointing me to that useful post, but I could not find the solution to my proble aka how to pass the values as computed by the ECMA model back to my managed code?

Comment: If you NEED the values in your code behind then you could have your javascript populate a hidden control which passes the values back to your code behind.  There is probably a cleaner way using services or callbacks, but this keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your modal dialogue could trigger a postback to the page and set the user-entered values put into the query string, which could be read by the web part.

Comment: Putting user entered data into the query string is not the securest method of transport, even in a cross page scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can return values from a modal dialog by the use of 'commonModalDialogClose()'.

Here you can find an example how to do so:
http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/a-better-user-experience-with-the-dialog-framework-and-notifications/